# CPU-Z say the SPD RANK number is "dual" and “single?”

Tags: memory

So I have two Corsair 3000MHz RGB PRO RAM.

Installed on Slot 2 and Slot 4 and it shows correct 24GB running on 2933 MHz

But why on CPU-Z

[image: RANKS - Dual]

[image: RANKS - Single]

But it shows on Memory Tab as Ranks: Dual + Can someone confirm my clock speed? It shows 1465.8MHz but Task Manager shows 2933 MHz. Is my RAM not being used to 3000 MHz which it is set to or as I read a lot of threads before posting, 1465.8 x 2 MHz is the correct speed.

[image: RANK: DUAL *Plus confirm the clock speed of the RAM please]

Finally understand what Dual and Single RANK IS.\

[On the RIGHT SIDE - IT IS DUAL RANK and On the LEFT SIDE - IT IS SINGLE RANK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHe4X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Installed on Slot 2 and Slot 4 and it shows correct 24GB running on 2933 MHz

Your firmware confirmed your memory is running at 2933 MHz.

> But it shows on Memory Tab as Ranks: Dual

Your memory is running in Dual Channel Mode.  One module is a Single rank the other is Dual.  This is confirmed based on the specifications of each part number you provided for each memory module.

> It shows 1465.8MHz but Task Manager shows 2933 MHz.

Task Manager is reporting the correct frequency.

> So, it is okay to assume that my ram sticks are working on dual channel mode?

Dual Ranks is not equal to Dual Channel memory mode.

Answer (score 0):

So i used Google to know why it's writing "dual channel" on memory page, and "single rank" in spd page...

" Dual rank and dual channel are 2 completely different things, Dual Rank means both sides of the RAM Module itself have memory dies on it (instead of being single sided), Dual Channel basically means you have 2 sticks installed. "

I think that's why your 8 gig single/ 16gig dual rank (for 16 gig doesn't have enough space on 1 side?!)